# what iOS maximums are set for height width of HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, html, canvas

I came up with a design where I have a larger canvas nested inside my main one. The main one I will refer to as ctx.  I move the larger one around and ctx masks it nicely. I did my dev in chrome and safari and it works nicely.

When I host it and check on my iPad3 I discover some limitations.
*Apparently there is a maximum limit set to the height and width for an html5 canvas in iOS !*

So I stripped down my code to a basic handful of lines to do testing. A 2000 x 2000 canvas will nest fine and display on an iPad3 but when I go up to 3000 x 3000 it shows blank.

I'm now left with a burning question - what are these maximums and do they differ for older iOS devices?

I did try searches but I can't find the answer so I turn to stackoverflow for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into this before as well, I think the problem is the amount of available video memory. It's not a specific width/height that is a problem, it's the width multiplied by the height, and the actual number is probably hardware specific.

Hate to say it, but I think you're just going to have to try it out and see what you can/can't get away with. Design your app around that restriction.

Note that the iPad 3's retina display means this it actually has slightly worse video performance than older generations.

Comment: What worries me is if it varies from device to device and I don't own every iOS device. Lets say I wanted it at very least to run on IPhone3. What maximum would you use?

Comment: If it's a 32 bit limitation, then the max would be 2048x2048. But 3000x1000 is probably fine.

Comment: Another similar limitation is JPEG images. A jpeg image must be smaller than 1024x1024 to render on an iPad. This means that 1775x1180 is fine, but 1776x1181 will fail... and the limitation only applies to non-progressive jpeg images. A progressive jpeg can be much larger, and a gif or png can also be much larger. Basically, there are some things that can only be tested by having access to the hardware.

Comment: Did you make a typo? 1775x1180 is bigger than 1024x1024

Comment: No worries... BTW, you're new here? It's customary to tap "upvote" on anything that helped you at all in the slightest... even comments and answers that aren't perfect.

Comment: I got a message saying Vote Up requires 15 reputation points and I only have 1.  If anyone reputable reads this please upvote him for me :)

Comment: I just upvoted a few of your things, you have a rep of 6 now. Go and answer/comment on a few other people's questions, write well thought out stuff, maybe edit other people's questions (fix typos, etc). You will even get rep for accepting someone's answer to this question (probably not mine, since i only half answered it). Before you know it you'll have a couple hundred rep. Once you've got that, any other stack exchange network account you create will automatically start out with enough rep to do all the basic stuff.